# How to show multiple layout in tools:listitem namespace of the RecyclerVIew xml

Tags: android, layout

I have a RecyclerView with different Types of ViewHolders, that have different layout resources. Is there a way to specify all layouts in the tools:listItem namespace? If I specify all listItems layout like this:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        ......

        tools:listitem="@layout/layout_1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/layout_2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/layout_3" />
```

I got an error because of duplicated items. I could do something like this:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  
        ......

        tools:listitem0="@layout/layout_1"
        tools:listitem1="@layout/layout_2"
        tools:listitem2="@layout/layout_3" />
```

The error is not presented but the clicking functionality that opens the layout is lost because there is no such declaration in the namespace.
It is the same when tools:showIn is used.

Answer (score 5):

The `tools:listitem` attribute accepts only a single item type so one possible and easy way is to define all your different layouts in a separate xml file using the `<include/>` tag with a parent of LinearLayout.

1.Create **res->layout->item_multiple_layouts.xml** and define all your layouts in the order you wish to appear in the RecyclerView using a Vertical LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/item_type_1" />
    <include layout="@layout/item_type_2" />
    <include layout="@layout/item_type_3" />
    <include layout="@layout/item_type_1" />
    <include layout="@layout/item_type_2" />
    <include layout="@layout/item_type_3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2.To preview the above layouts in the RecyclerView you can point to the above layout with itemCount=1 to render them only once like below:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_multiple_layouts"
    tools:itemCount="1"/>
```

Comment: Nice, solution, I like it. It is a better solution than manually change the tools:listitem0="..." to tools:listitem="...", but it is still a hacky way ;).  You should click twice to navigate to the desired layout.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as a "tools-only" layout, so it doesn't get compiled into the output, and so no one can accidentally use it from code? Not critical, but would be a nice touch, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I think there isn't any clean way to do this.
If you want to preview the same layout multiple items, here's what you can do:

```
tools:listitem="@layout/layout_1"
tools:itemCount="5"
```

There is a different approach to implement a custom ViewFlipper for this purpose. But I find that as overkill. I'll just run the application instead of writing that code :P

Here's the link:
https://medium.com/@AllanHasegawa/previewing-multiples-item-types-in-a-recyclerview-163aebc2f34a

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, let's say that I have 5 items but each item has a different layout. I what to have quick access to them in the RecylerView tag.

Comment: The simplest way would be to swap different layouts manually.
Like, substitute layout1 and observe on the right panel. Then do that same for others.